# Corollary of Noether's normalization lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $R\subset S$ be domains such that $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra. Show that there exists $f\in R$, $f\neq0$, and elements $y_1,\dots,y_r\in S$ algebraically independent over $R$ such that $S_f$ is integral over $S'_{f}$, where $S'=R[y_1,\dots,y_r]$.

I am trying to prove it via Noether's normalization lemma; but I am not able to solve this problem, despite various attempts. Any help or hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show or describe your attempts to help us give you better hints/answers? For example, Noether Normalization deals with finitely generated algebras over a field - how have you gotten to this setup? (If you haven't, there's the first hint - find a way to get to this setup.)

Comment: @KReiser Well I have done something like if $S$ is a finitely generated $R$algebra, with $R$ being a domain. Then $S=R[x_1,x_2,..x_r]$, now we can localize this R with respect to $T=R-0$, and can get fraction field $K$ of $R$, then we can say $K[x_1,....x_m]$ is finitely generated over $K$. And use noether's normalization. But then that would be for whole set $T\in R$, not a single element $f \in R$